# Rails: Add attribute to nested attributes in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, strong-parameters

I have a model called `Litter` that accepts nested attributes for the model `Puppy`.  When submitting an update to a litter I want to modify all the nested puppies so it adds a new attribute (breed_id). This is because the breed_id can be inferred from the litter and I don't want the user to specify it for every puppy. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
  def update

    litter_params[:puppies_attributes].each do |puppy|
      puppy[1][:breed_id] = litter_params[:breed_id]
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @litter.update(litter_params)
        format.html { redirect_to litters_url, notice: "Litter was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @litter }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @litter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

However, for some reason the puppy nested attributes continue to not include the new attribute (breed_id):

```
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "litter"=>{"dog_ids"=>["", "3", "10"], "breed_id"=>"115", "puppies_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"Oscar", "id"=>"31"}, "1623432054943"=>{"_destroy"=>"false", "name"=>"James"}}}, "commit"=>"Update Litter", "id"=>"11"}
```

Any idea how I can add this attribute to the nested models?

This is my `litter_params` by the way:

```
    def litter_params
      params.require(:litter).permit(:breed_id, :breeder_id, dog_ids: [], puppies_attributes: [:_destroy, :id, :name])
    end
```

Comment: If a puppy belongs to a litter and a litter has many puppies, you can try to add a relationship to the puppy model, `has_one :breed, through: :litter`. Then you could add a method for the column name you want, `def breed_id; @_breed_id ||= breed.id; end`

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery At the moment the puppy `belongs_to :breed`

Comment: @engineersmnky This is actually handled separately within the breed model.

Comment: Easiest way to do what you want is likely `litter_params[:puppies_attributes].each {|_,puppy| puppy.merge!(breed_id:  litter_params[:breed_id])}` or actually setting this in the UI before the params are passed.

Comment: I would just reference the litter's breed through the puppy. That way if the breed ever hsa to change for the litter, the puppy's reference to it will change as well